# New to multithreading- most cost efficient way to multithread?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, irc

So I have worked with Multithreading in small application. Create a new thread here, a new thread there.

I'm currently working on a program that monitors an IRC chat. For every valid command it creates a thread, does some work, and outputs the result to the chat. At times the application will get 10  or more valid commands in a short time and 10 or more threads are created. The application starts to really slow down. I've read that creating and closing threads is very cost inefficient with resources so I want to change my method.

An idea I've had is to create some threads (5 or so?) that are always running with a method that I pass commands to that queues them in a FIFO basis. Before I implemented this I wanted to see if there is something better I should be using. I don't want to run off and reinvent the wheel, of course.

Comment: Consider [java thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: `ExecutorService executor =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a fixed size [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) thread poll.  Submit each message to send as a task and they will be sent as there is a free thread. e.g.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

Note: this can lead to messages being sent out of order so your client should be able to reorder the messages based on a timestamp.

---

BTW: If 10 command at once is notably slow, it's not the creating of threads which will be causing this. Threads are expensive yes, but not that expensive. Instead it is likely to network delays or some other blocking operation.  You may need to create qa queue for each client if you have poor network connections.

Comment: Mention `Executors`, maybe?

Comment: I do have some methods that are required to be synchronized. Its really those commands that get slow if there are many at once. Which is sort of expected. But it takes about 10 seconds if 10 of those commands are called before the 11th command is handled. (if that makes sense)

Comment: @meriley I work try to determine why these commands take so long. I would expect you can send at least 50K chat messages per second, ideally over 300K/s.